# php ROUNDDOWN double number for versioning

Tags: php

I put the version number in `double` variables.

For example, I want to show like this,

```
(Internal) (show )
a 1.10000 -> 1.1
b 1.20000 -> 1.2
c 1.14000 -> 1.14
```

There is a bit problem versioning is not real double.

It's something like two int number combined by `.`

`round($num,1)` this doesnt work for case c.

`round($num,2)` this shows 1.10,1.20 as case a, case b.

Do you know any good way??

Comment: Yes, a floating point number is rather inconvenient for version numbers. For instance, my current browser version is `67.0.4` and my secondary browser is at `75.0.3770.100`. Can you edit the question and add more details about how you get such data in a double variables in the first place? Otherwise you aren't going to get any advice that's actually accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would not store your version numbers as numbers because, well, they aren't really numbers -- you don't do math on them, except for comparison. If possible, you would want to store them as strings (following [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) is a good idea, but your current approach will also work with strings) and use `version_compare` to compare them.

That said, if you can no longer move to a string-based versioning system, you can still treat your double as a string and just... cut the zeros:

```
preg_replace('/0+$/', '', $num)
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: Like your suggestion, but your regex may fail on versions like `1.0000`, resulting in `1.`

Comment: I see. I decided to use as string.

Answer (score 2):

```
rtrim($num, '0.');
```

Just trim all trailing `0` and `.` from the right.

```
$numbers = ['a' => '1.10000', 'b' => '1.20000', 'c' => '1.14000', 'd' => '1.0000'];

foreach($numbers as $key => $num) {
 echo $key . ': ' . rtrim($num, '0.') . '<br>';
}

// output:
// a: 1.1
// b: 1.2
// c: 1.14
// d: 1
```

(I added case `d` to show it handles this “edge case” mentioned in a comment on the other answer fine as well.)